# Rails 5 Route accepts JSON without a Content-Type header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I've written an api with rails and want a client to be able to send JSON data without a `Content-Type` header. I've already given the namespace the default format of JSON:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do

end
```

Is it possible to have the route assume all incoming requests are JSON so that the client doesn't need to specify the Content-Type? Right now, if a content-type header isn't set, all incoming requests are assumed to be of text type.

Comment: Why not just test it? It would have taken you less time than writing the question and revealed that thats exactly what setting the default format does...

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear. I know the above code works. If I have an iOS app that is making requests to my rails server I need to set a content-type header of application/json otherwise my rails app will assume the content-type is text when receiving the request from the iOS app. Is there a way for my rails app to assume incoming requests are type application/json instead of text? The above code does not do that.

Comment: is there no other content-types you are serving? you could just always do `render json: the_data` in your controllers. that is what rails-api does https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/e150fb9555a1de863711055308a066f607d6edab/lib/rails-api/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb#L10

Comment: I think this might just be a stupid question. An iOS dev I work with didn't want to have to set a content-type header, so I was wondering if I could just set all incoming requests with the content type of JSON. I'm already serving only JSON.